# Access violation in Masm when accessing memory offset

Tags: sorting, x86, access-violation, masm

I'm trying to to a selection sort in x86 assembly and I'm getting an access error violation when I try to use a variable to access an offset of an array.

```
.data
array BYTE "fairy tale"
count = ($ - array)
minIndex BYTE ?

.code
_main PROC

mov eax, 0                          
mov ebx, 0                          

mov ecx, count                      ; move array count to counter register
dec ecx                             ; decrease counter
lea esi, array


mov bl, 0                           ; i = 0
L1:
push ecx        


mov minIndex, bl                    ; minIndex = i
mov al, minIndex[esi]               ; THIS GIVES THE ERROR

; rest of code...

ret

_main ENDP

END _main
```

There are no build errors, only the access violation at run time. Are you not allowed to do such an operation in MASM? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov al, minIndex[esi]
```

If you think that will take the value of `minIndex` and use that to offset `esi` in the read operation, then you're incorrect. What it will do is use *the address of* `minIndex`.

You can change your code to:

```
movzx eax,byte ptr minIndex  ; zero-extend the byte at minIndex into eax..
mov al,[esi+eax]             ; ..and use that as an offset into the array
```

Comment: Okay that's what I thought was happening but I wasn't sure how to get it to act the way I wanted. Thanks !